# Java Arrays Binary Search

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, binary-search

I do not have more information on *Arrays.binarySearch*. Arrays.binarysearch exactly what they're doing. Why 3 -3 console output;

```
import java.util.*;
    public class VLA2 implements Comparator<VLA2> {
        int dishSize;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            VLA2[] va = {new VLA2(40), new VLA2(200), new VLA2(60) ,new VLA2(70)};
            Arrays.sort(va, va[0]);

            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(va, new VLA2(40), va[0]);
            System.out.print(index + " ");
            index = Arrays.binarySearch(va, new VLA2(69), va[0]);
            System.out.print(index);
        }
        public int compare(VLA2 a, VLA2 b) {
            return b.dishSize - a.dishSize;
        }
        VLA2(int d) { dishSize = d; }
    }
```

Comment: Does the way in which you add elements to `va` yield a sorted array?

Comment: I wrote the OCP example.I get why you give minus points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is sorted to `{200, 70, 60, 40}`, because your `compare()` method returns a positive value when `a.dishSize < b.dishSize`.

**Hence when you search for a VLA2(40), you find it at position 3.**

**When you search for VLA2(69), it's not found. So by definition, the return value of the method is `-insertion_point - 1`.** In this case, the insertion point would be 2, so the return value is -3.

The `Arrays.sort()` method does sort in ascending order. But the relationship between members is defined by your comparator. **By definition, your comparator must return a negative value when a < b, and a positive value when a > b.** If you want the ascending order to be natural, change your `compare()` method to return a.dishSize - b.dishSize.

**By the way,** it's unusual for an object to be its own comparator. Ideally a class represents exactly one concept. In this case, mixing two concepts into one class results in calls like this:

```
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(va, new VLA2(40), va[0]);
```

Here, you're passing va[0], not to use it as a VLA2 value, but to use it as a comparator. This can be somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 1):

After sort your array it would look like
{200,70,60,40} as your comparator sorts in decending order.

```
  int index = Arrays.binarySearch(va, new VLA2(40), va[0]);
```

This will return index of 40 in the sorted array ie 3

In case if the element is not present in the array , binarySearch method will return the  (-(insertion point) -1). Insertion point is the index into which the element should be inserted to keep the array in sorted order.
Here

```
    index = Arrays.binarySearch(va, new VLA2(69), va[0]);
```

To keep the array sorted 69 should be inserted in index=2
`{200,70,69,60,40}`
So (-2)-1 = -3 . So binary Search returns -3.
Please note that 69 would not be inserted. Only insertion point will be calculated by the binarySearch function.

If you are searching for 269,
To keep the array sorted 269 should be inserted in index=0
`{269,200,70,...}`
So the `binarySearch()` returns -0-1 = -1